# 4 graphs for each user, need to show the fourth graph in different layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, iteration

In my app each user has 4X graphs to display.

I'm displaying 3X `col-md-4` graphs for each user through the  `each loop` below.

This code is in my view.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
    <% @user_overviews.each do |overview| %>

        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <h4><%= overview.title %></h4>
        <%= raw overview.graph%>
        </div>


    <% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

the problem is that I need to be able to show a fourth graph below the other three graphs in a `col-md-12`.

I'm using active admin to upload the graphs, so the four graphs for user 1 have ID 1,2,3,4  and the next four graphs for user 2 have ID 5, 6, 7, 8  and so on.

So in graph 4 and 8 are the once that should be displayed in the `col-md-12`

I find it hard to get around how I can display graph 4 and 8 in a `col-md-12`

can someone advise me on how I would do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all (unless I'm missing something), the `row` div should be the child of the `container` div.

Given that the overviews will always be of fixed sized 4, try using the `each_with_index` method as shown below:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <% @user_overviews.each_with_index do |overview, index| %>
            <div class="col-md-<%= index == 3 ? '12' : '4' %> text-center">
                <h4><%= overview.title %></h4>
                <%= raw overview.graph%>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is great and works perfectly, you saved my day :)

Comment: Glad I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

If each user has exactly 4 overviews, probably a simple solution is to iterate over all except the last one and then put another row for the last overview. You will need another row anyway if you want to have `col-md-12`.

Also, I think the container div has to wrap everything else.

Something like this maybe:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <% @user_overviews[0...-1].each do |overview| %>
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <h4><%= overview.title %></h4>
                <%= raw overview.graph %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h4><%= @user_overviews.last.title %></h4>
            <%= raw overview.graph %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit: Lazarus' solution is more DRY, so I think it's better.